# Do activities in a project get compiled into the .apk if they are not referenced in the Android Manifest .xml?

Tags: android, eclipse, reverse-engineering, android-activity, apk

I have a developer eyes-only activity that I don't want end users to reverse engineer to find. In my local project, I have it defined. But on deployment, I do not want this activity to be available at all . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the activity will still be in the APK... but it will never be seen by the system, and thus can never be launched.

If you really care about preventing users from reverse engineering your APK, the simple solution would be to just take the activity out of your project all together. Ideally you would want your downloadable APK to be as small as possible anyway. If you want to keep the activity for deployment purposes, then you could always clone your current project and keep it as a backup on your local machine.

Comment: I guess I won't be hardcoding the dozens of username and passwords I use during development against different environments.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

With this tool, you can obfuscate the code and configure what classes should be packaged in the apk.